# statement exposure in poisson regression using R

Tags: regression, poisson

I am trying to fit the model from Frome(1983) in R using poisson Regression, but i dont know how add the exposure: ln(person-years), the model is:

ln E(Y|X)= ln(person-years)+ B0+ B1X1+ B2X2.

Do you know how fit that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform poisson regression analysis using the below R code.

`m1<- glm(y  ~  offset(log(person-years))+X1+X2, family="poisson",  data=dat)
summary(m1)`

Because you use an offset of 'log(person-years)', the coefficient of 'log(person-years)' is forced to be 1.